# Wordpress Options Table Deleting All Values When Saving Subset of Entries

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that uses Wordpress Options - it saves data for each page and post, tagged with the ID, that I can pull out on the front end and display custom data for that post or page.

For example, I can enter custom data for each of posts 1-25, save successfully to Options.php, go to page 2 where I see post entries 26-50, and save data for those entries...but saving the data for 26-50 wipes the data I just saved on entries 1-25 and 51-*x*

The pagination code I'm using is a custom snippet:

```
$how_many_results = 25;
$post_args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'posts_per_page' => $how_many_results, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged,'post_type' => 'post')
$posts_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
$mnposts = $posts_query->max_num_pages;
$big = 999999999999;
$posts_pagination = paginate_links(array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
'total' => $mnposts,
'end_size' => 1,
'mid_size' => 1,
'prev_next' => True,
'prev_text' => __('Prev','cust_dataset'),
'next_text' => __('Next','cust_dataset'),
'type' => 'list'
));
echo (!isset($posts_pagination))?'<span>'.__('All posts displayed','cust_dataset').'</span>':$posts_pagination;
```

And this is the HTML formatting:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php
settings_fields('cust_options_post');
$cust_posts = get_option('cust_settings_post');
$cust_name = 'cust_name_'.get_the_ID();
$cust_name_set = (isset($cust_posts[$cust_name]))?$cust_posts[$cust_name]:'';
$option .= '<input type="hidden" name="cust_settings_post['.get_permalink().']" id="cust_settings_post['.get_permalink().']" value="'.$red_url.'" />';
$option .= '<strong>' . get_the_title() . '</strong> (<em><a href="' . get_admin_url() . 'post.php?post=' . get_the_ID() . '&action=edit">edit</a></em>)';
$option .= '<br />' . get_permalink() . ' (<em><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">view</a></em>)';
$option .= '<input type="text" name="cust_settings_post['.$cust_name.']" id="cust_settings_post['.$cust_name.']" value="'.$cust_name_set.'" />';
?>
<?php echo $option; ?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that the Pagination is only pulling 25 at a time and Wordpress is re-saving the entire Options block on every form submit, even though it's a subset of only 25 entries. It wouldn't be a problem if I had 100 pages, but I am running it on a site that has over 30,000 posts ...and I can't bog the server down processing 30,000 Options datasets at a time.

**My question is: How do I save a subset of data to Options.php and NOT delete the remainder of the data I had previously saved that *is not* in the current subset?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more research I'll answer my own question for those who may follow.

Settings fields are stored in the Wordpress Options table as a single database table entry. Therefore, when you modify and save on bit of information, or in this case a subset of that information, Wordpress re-writes the entire table entry for that Settings field, so it overwrites itself every time it saves.

The only way to save the remainder of your data in that entry is to pull it out and store it in a variable that you then append to the modified code before re-saving it. The problem with this, however, is when you begin dealing with large amounts of data. In my case, I was saving additional bits of data for each of 30,000 posts, which is a good way to use up all the memory on your server trying to process the bits of data for those pages...even when you're only looking at a subset of 25 or 50 entries.

There you go.